# Prevent draggable to be dropped at the end of sortable - jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a problem and I couldn't find solution anywhere. Or I'm just missing something.

I have two lists - draggable and sortable. I use the option **items** in the sortable.

When the disabled items are at the beginning of the list, I can't place the draggable item at the first position which I find good in my case. But if the disabled items are the last ones, the draggable item can be dropped at last position.

I have also tried with the **cancel** option in both sortable and draggable lists but without any luck.

Does anyone know a solution so I can't drop either to first neither to last position.

Here is my fiddle: [jsBin example](https://jsbin.com/dujusecoco/edit?html,js,output). In Example 1 is the first case and in Example 2 is the second.

Or **HTML**:

```
<h2>Example 1</h2>

<h4>Sortable</h4>
<ul class="sortable1">
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">Item 1 disabled</li>
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">Item 2 disabled</li>
  <li>Item 3 not disabled</li>
</ul>

<h4>Draggable</h4>
<ul class="draggable1">
  <li>Item 1 to drag</li>
  <li>Item 2 to drag</li>
  <li>Item 3 to drag</li>
</ul>



<h2>Example 2</h2>

<h4>Sortable</h4>

<ul class="sortable2">
  <li>Item 1 not disabled</li>
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">Item 2 disabled</li>
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">Item 3 disabled</li>
</ul>

<h4>Draggable</h4>
<ul class="draggable2">
  <li>Item 1 to drag</li>
  <li>Item 2 to drag</li>
  <li>Item 3 to drag</li>
</ul>

<style>
  .placeholder {border: 1px solid #ccc; height: 20px;}
</style>
```

And **JS**:

```
$('.draggable1 li').draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  helper: 'clone',
  connectToSortable: '.sortable1',
  cancel: '.ui-state-disabled'
});

$('.sortable1').sortable({
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  items: '*:not(".ui-state-disabled")',
  placeholder: 'placeholder',
  cancel: '.ui-state-disabled'
});



$('.draggable2 li').draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  helper: 'clone',
  connectToSortable: '.sortable2',
  cancel: '.ui-state-disabled'
});

$('.sortable2').sortable({
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  items: '*:not(".ui-state-disabled")',
  placeholder: 'placeholder',
  cancel: '.ui-state-disabled'
});
```